# I dockerized my angular app and was using json server as backend aand no backend logic is available when i run the docker image

Tags: json, server, dockerfile

I dockerized my angular app and was using json server as backend with db.json file. However when I run the docker image without running the json server on the terminal, no logic is available. buttons don't work and data i had in the db is not available. Here is the docker file:

```
FROM node:14.20 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod


FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/invoice-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I tried the command 'RUN npm run dbrun' after 5th Dockerfile line, which runs the db.json file when building the image but the image was not completing, it only would open json server and stop there without completing image build.

Below is the image when i run the app with ng serve command and also the json server concurrently:[proper running app on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4xEi.png)

And here is the image when only docker image is running:[Buttons to post request etc have no functionality and no data present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jMhc.png)